# Non-webkit rotateY animation with Jquery's Transform3d

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, webkit, transform

I have been messing around with Jquery's transform3d plugin, developed by heygrady (https://github.com/heygrady/transform3d). And what I want to achieve is to rotate a div along the Y axis, to "fake" the flip effect that can be easily done with CSS3. But I want to do this with Jquery to make it work non-webkit browsers as well.

In the test.html example file (which can be downloaded from the heygrady's github), the author wrote the following code:

`$('img:first').transform3d({perspective: 400, rotateY: '0deg', rotateX: '30deg'}, {nudge: 1.02, quality: 7}).animate({rotateY: '60deg'}, 5000);`

The transform3d function works fine on it's own. But the animate function with the rotateY parameter is not really working. So I was wondering whether I am missing something or there is a bug somewhere. My JS skills are limited so I have no clue where to look for..

Any help would be appreciated!

Cheers,
Dandoen

Comment: anyone? i have tried a lot, but still no luck :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the latest version of the plugin on GitHub, seems animation doesn't actually work yet. I just get a lot of javascript errors.

Comment: That's true. I got a reply on the issue I posted on GitHub, and the author confirmed the code contains all kind of errors. Probably not worth for him to continue working on it. In my case, I gave up cross browser compatibility and went ahead with CSS3 3d transform.